# Two Button OnClickListeners inside for loop

Tags: android, button, android-button

I am self studying Android and now I am learning how to use buttons. I created a simple up counter which works like this: 
I add the strings (eg. 1 2 3) in different text fields. Then I want to compaire those in pairs(1 with 2, 1 with 3, 2 with 3). The first string element is written on the first button, second on the second and after i press any of those buttons, the tags on the buttons has to change (if there was 1 and 2 so it should change to 1 and 3 or 2 and 3 etc) and the string element gets a higher rank. Everything seems to work well, but I think I am doing huge mistake with adding buttons. Can anyone help me? :) Can I add button listeners like I did in code bellow? :) Thank You!

```
public void counter() 
{
    int i = 0;
    int a = i + 1;

    for ( i = 0; i < candidates.size() - 1; i++ ) 
    {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting button one tag: " + i );
            button_one.setTag(i);
            button_one.setText(candidates.get(i).name);

            for (a = i + 1; a < candidates.size(); a++)
            {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting button two tag: " + a );
            button_two.setTag(a);
            button_two.setText(candidates.get(a).name);

            button_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    /* Read the clicked tag */
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();

                    /* Make higher rank */
                    candidates.get(tag).addRank();
                }
            });

            button_two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    /* Read the clicked tag */
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();

                    /* Make higher rank */
                    candidates.get(tag).addRank();
                }
            }); 
            }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything AndyRes said plus:
you're creating (candidates.size() * candidates.size()) number of OnClickListeners
that's A LOT of unnecessary objects hogging your memory.

You should create ONE `OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener etc... etc...`
and OUTSIDE the loop, probably during your `OnCreate()` just after you defined `button_one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);` you do `button_one.setOnClickListener(mListener);`

that way you have only 1 listener that will be serving any amount of buttons you might have, and don't need to be setting again the same listener.

Comment: And the OnClickListener mListener should be inside the loop or also outside?

Comment: Outside. The OnClickListener mListener should be a private object of the class you're implementing. You said you're self-studying. It sounds a bit to me that you come from a not object orientation background (been there bro). If that's correct, I suggest you get some reading on object orientation before diving into Android. Just the basics of class/objects/instantiation/etc

Answer (score 0):

In general there's not need to add the click listeners in a loop, unless you create those buttons dinamically.

Setting the click listeners in a loop for the same button, every time you cycle through the loop, will do nothing but override the previous settings, so I don't see any point in doing like this.

Comment: It depends. I said, unless you create the buttons dinamicaly (from the code), it's OK to use a loop to set click listeners. But if you have for example 2 buttons in your XML layout and want to set a click listener for them, then just after I get the reference to the button `Button myButton=(Buttom)findViewById(...);`, I would set the click listener `myButton.setOnClickListener(...);`. Not inside a loop.

Comment: Just set the listener and override the onclick() methodoutside the loop.

Comment: You mean that I should add 

button_one.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClicked());
    button_two.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClicked());

inside the loop and then make ButtonClicked class outside the counter function? :)

Comment: @JuozasA No i dont think it will work.
Instead use  button_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    /* Read the clicked tag */
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();

                    /* Make higher rank */
                    candidates.get(tag).addRank();
                }
            });
 outside the loop